# How to add a validation rule to jquery.validation

Tags: jquery, validation

Actually I am using jquery validation plug-in to validate a form.
In a form I m using 3 dropdown list.
And I want 
-> when I will choose a value in drop-downlist-1 ,the similar value in drop-downlist-2 and drop-downlist-3 shouldn't be choosen atall.
and I want to be done by validation rule of validation plug-in.

can anyone solve my problem ?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @ntziolis is right, after i seen that i didn't even read the question.

Comment: @ntziolis- thanx for ur suggestion .I will work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dropdowns", function(value, element) {

          var drop_val1 = $('#drop_1').val();
          var drop_val2 = $('#drop_2').val();
          var drop_val3 = $('#drop_3').val();


          if((parseInt(drop_val1)==parseInt(drop_val2)) || (parseInt(drop_val1)==parseInt(drop_val3)) || (parseInt(drop_val2)==parseInt(drop_val3)))
          { 
               return false;
          }
          else
         {
              return true;
         }


  }, "can not have the same value in 2 dropdowns");
```

then add it to your validation

```
            dropdown: {
                required : true,
                dropdowns: true
            }
```

this should work

**EDIT**

this works for multiple dropdowns

```
            dropdown1: {
                required : true,
                dropdowns: true
            },



            dropdown2: {
                required : true,
                dropdowns: true
            },



            dropdown3: {
                required : true,
                dropdowns: true
            }
```

`dropdown1 , dropdown2 ,dropdown3`  are your dropdown names

Comment: thanks... but I want to create a validation rule for the problem. So can u describe how to do the same?

Comment: @Kaniska Panamaldeniya : But this code doesn't work on multiple dropdowns. Then how to work on multiple dropdowns?